# Bootcamp Partition in Mac

Tags: boot-camp

I have managed to mess up my BootCamp partition and need help! I used Disk Utility to extend the size of my partition, then tried to return to Windows 7 to modify it there, but was unable to open Windows. After searching the internet, I tried to follow some directions on repairing the partition Master Boot Table using rEFIt and messed it up further.

```
Last login: Wed Jun 22 10:29:50 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~ scottmiller$ diskutil list
[enter image description here][1]
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            190.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s6
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                200.0 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +299.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 45BC9F39-0037-4A6F-AAB4-0A0B49D6328B
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
MacBook-Pro:~ scottmiller$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 60821/255/63 [977105060 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AC 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  371804104] <Unknown ID>
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 372213744 -    1269760] Darwin Boot 
 4: 0C 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 586481664 -  390623232] Win95 FAT32L
MacBook-Pro:~ scottmiller$ sudo gpt -v -r show /dev/disk0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  371804104      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  372213744    1269760      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  373483504  212998160         
  586481664  390623232      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  977104896        131         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
MacBook-Pro:~ scottmiller$
```

Comment: If I am correct, the 0 partition should show the MBR, not the GUID_partition_scheme, but I am not sure how to change it without screwing it up more!

Comment: Well, I managed to mess it up more! I am now using my phone to get help.  Now I cannot restart Mac OS without getting a Circle/slash icon!